# Custom image generator function interpreted as a generator object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently learned that Python interprets functions with return and functions with yield separately.
I made this custom generator that uses Keras ImageDataGenerator to generates batches of images from a directory into a GAN Deep Learning network:

```
def loadRealImages(batch):
for gen in pixGen.flow_from_directory(picturesPath, target_size = (256, 256),
                                    batch_size = batch, class_mode = "binary"):
    realImgs = [image for image in gen]
    yield realImgs[0]
```

My program expect what this generator yields (tensor of batch images) to run an analysis through a network and output a prediction:

```
real = loadRealImages(1) # get one real image
prediction = discriminator([real, fake]) # check similarity
```

My problem is that because of the call to the custom generator, **real** is considered a **generator object loadRealImages** when the program is expecting an image in tensor form and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '_keras_mask_'
```

From what I found looking into the problem, it seems generators don't get executed during interpretation. Then how should I bypass this check during interpretation?

PS: in this particular line, I only need one image so I could load it in a different way but I have others of these generator calls throughout the code and I can't really delete them.

Comment: When you do `real = loadRealImages(1)` nothing is being executed , as it is a generator , not a function. All you get is a `<class 'generator'>` object. You have to either manually call `next()` go obtain a value or use an iterator(or `for` loop ) to get the result. Take a look at the [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for more information

Comment: I see. I'll go check out the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the keras library, but generators are a bit different from functions in that calling them returns a generator, *not* the first `yield` object. You have to call `next` on the returned generator to get the image

```py
def img_generator(num_imgs):
  for ii in range(num_imgs):
    yield np.random.random((256, 256)) > 0

one_img_generator = img_generator(1)
img = next(one_img_generator)
next(one_img_generator) # will raise StopIteration
```

Does that make sense?

Your generator could also be made more 'natural', i.e. the pythonic way of writing it would be:

```py
def loadRealImages(batch):
  for gen in pixGen.flow_from_directory(picturesPath, target_size = (256, 256),
                                    batch_size = batch, class_mode = "binary"):
    yield next(gen)
```

This way, the whole list isn't placed into memory at the same time (if `gen` is a generator). Instead, only the requested element is in memory.

Comment: Oh I see. It makes a lot of sense. I guess I didn't know that much about python generator objects. Let me try this.

Comment: So I tried the change you suggested in your edit to my **loadRealImages ( )** but it didn't solve the issue. But I tried using the call to **next ( )** on the line where I make the call to the generator instead right before it gets assigned to the variable:
   `real = next(loadRealImages(1))`
This solved the issue and now the script is looking for the path to the picture.